# Advice on structuring access control in database using entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, forms-authentication, database-schema

I am looking for some advice and assistance with an architecture I am attempting to implement. The application I am building provides SSO and central authentication for multiple ASP.NET websites that we use internally. The problem I am facing is that I cannot seem to come up with a way to structure my data in entity framework that makes sense.

Overview:
1) An account can be associated with many applications
2) Roles are specific to each application
3) Features are specific to each application
4) It is not shown below but I would like to further break down the associations and make Accounts members of “Directories” and an application can access users within a list of directories associated with the application (does this make sense?)
A user “Joe” would have permissions like below:

```
Application 1:  

Role    | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3
=============================================
Role1   |     x     |           |     x
Role2   |           |     x     |     x
Role3   |     x     |     x     |     x

Application 2:
Role    | Feature 1 | Feature 2 | Feature 3
=============================================
Role1   |           |           |     x
Role2   |           |     x     |     
Role3   |     x     |     x     |     x
```

I would access these permissions via an API similar to:

```
CheckAccountPermission(Role, Feature), IsAccountInRole(Role)
```

Currently, I have been trying the following model:

```
Application.cs
public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
public Guid ApplicationGuid { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Directory> Directories { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Feature> Features { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AccountPermission> AccountPermissions { get; set; } 


Account.cs
public int AccountId { get; set; }
public string Username { get; set; }
public string Password { get; set; }
public string PasswordSalt { get; set; }
public string FirstName { get; set; }
public string MiddleName { get; set; }
public string LastName { get; set; }
public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
public string AvatarUrl { get; set; }
public string AccountNotes { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastLogin { get; set; }
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastActivity { get; set; }
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
//-------------------//
public int DirectoryId { get; set; }
public virtual Directory Directory { get; set; }            
public virtual ICollection<Session> Sessions { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AccountPermission> AccountPermissions { get; set; } 

Directory.cs
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Account> Accounts { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<Application> Applications { get; set; } 

Role.cs
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Description { get; set; }
public int? PrimaryRoleId { get; set; }
public Role PrimaryRole { get; set; }
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
public DateTime? LastModified { get; set; }
public virtual int DirectoryId { get; set; }
public virtual Directory Directory { get; set; }
public virtual ICollection<AccountPermission> AccountPermissions { get; set; } 

AccountPermission.cs
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
public int AccountId { get; set; }
public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 1)]
public int RoleId { get; set; }
public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 2)]
public int FeatureId { get; set; }
public virtual Feature Feature { get; set; }
[Key, Column(Order = 3)]
public int ApplicationId { get; set; }
public virtual Application Application { get; set; }
```

If I am off base or misguided here, please feel free to point me in the right direction. I really want to get this right. Any clarifying information I can provide, please let me know!
Thanks everyone!

Comment: if you are using MVC have considered using simple membership before creating your own user profiles? heres some info on simple memebership http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter

Comment: Thank you, Yugz. I looked into using simple membership to begin with. However, I cannot see how it affords me the "Features" requirement we have plus the requirement for application segregation.